# What does a Perl module have to do to make it to the CORE load?

Tags: perl

This question stems from curiosity more than anything else.

If one was to sit down and write a Perl module with the sole objective of getting that module to eventually become a part of the `CORE` load, what factors should they pay attention to? Here are a few that spring to mind, though I'm sure there are exceptions to every one of them:

- Usefulness
- Maturity
- Stability
- Core-modules-only dependency
- Problem area being solved
- Cross-platform compatibility
- CPAN testers review
- Reviews

Also, am I right in assuming that the Perl 5 Porters make the final call on whether to include something in the core load or not?

Comment: Write something that's useful and ends up being heavily adopted in the CPAN.

Comment: @JackManey : Just 'cos it's useful doesn't mean it qualifies for the CORE load (e.g. `XML::LibXML`). The question is about the selection criteria, not what makes a module useful or not

Comment: Perl5 Porters make the first call. The pumpkin has the final call, though it would likely be in the vein of "I'd like to see XXX addressed first". Larry Wall could technically veto, although he's not likely to be the least bit involved.

Comment: Two more factors: 1) Lack of ability to achieve the feature outside of core. 2) Not likely to be supplanted by the next fad.

Comment: @Jack Maney, In fact, one could argue that wide adoption on CPAN is a sign that there's no need for it to be included in the core. (No idea any of those "ones" are p5p.)

Comment: @ikegami : I'm just thinking here. `Re: Lack of ability to achieve the feature outside of core`, `Test::More` is part of CORE. Is testing considered to be core functionality? `Re: Simple, commonly required tool`, is something like [`use.pm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/use) expected to make it to `CORE`?

Comment: 1st "?") Like you've implied, these are merely factors to consider. No one factor will necessarily decide if something gets or doesn't get in. 2nd "?") I can't predict what would happen if someone asked to include use.pm (or any other module) in core.

Comment: Of note: There are very few requests to include a module in core.

Comment: The current focus of p5p, from what I can tell, is "Is this module required to download/compile/test/install modules from CPAN?".  They seem to have been more interested in removing modules from the corelist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are Perl's core libraries managed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967895/how-are-perls-core-libraries-managed)